# How to diagnose mixed visibility between PCs in a Windows workgroup?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, workgroup

In my home network, I have several PCs that are part of the same Windows Workgroup.

To add a PC to the same Workgroup, I

1. navigate to `System Properties > Computer Name` and ensure the `Workgroup` value is the same on all PCs, and
2. give each PC a unique name.

For example, the screenshot below is the `System Properties > Computer Name` window/tab from one of my PCs that's part of my `Home-workgroup` workgroup; other PCs have unique names, but the same Workgroup.

[image]

The screenshot above is from the PC named "Computer-1".
Other PCs in the workgroup are named "Computer-2" and "Computer-3".

When I need to access one PC in the workgroup from another, I open a file browser, and enter `\\<PC name>`.
E.g. from `Computer-1`, I would open a file browser and enter `\\computer-2` (case-sensitivity does not appear at issue here) in the address bar, as in the screenshot below.
[image]

With the above-described setup, I observe an odd pattern of ability/inability to "connect" (typing `\\<PC name>` in a file browser address bar) from one PC to another, and I can't determine a pattern or anything unique between PCs with ability or inability to access each other.

I observe:

1. `computer-1` --> `computer-2`: OK
2. `computer-1` --> `computer-3`: Doesn't work
3. `computer-2` --> `computer-1`: OK
4. `computer-2` --> `computer-3`: OK
5. `computer-3` --> `computer-1`: Doesn't work
6. `computer-3` --> `computer-2`: OK

At some point in the past, all PCs were able to "connect" to all other PCs.

The cumulative effect of all the various Windows updates over time seems to have caused this odd combination of ability/inability of the PCs to connect to each other.

My question is: **what are debugging tips for an inability of PCs in the same Windows workgroup to access each other?**

**Or: if this is common, what tend to be the underlying problems and fixes?**

Odd/noteworthy to me is that different PCs have different results connecting *to* the same PC.
I.e. it's presumably not a problem on the target PC, otherwise *no* PC would be able to connect to it(?)

I do not have any custom firewalls on any of the PCs -- it's the "standard" firewall that comes with Windows 10.

---

**Update:** Based on @SeñorCMasMas's suggestion, I tried entering `\\<IP address>` into each PC's respecting browser address bars, and I got the same results, i.e.:

1. `computer-1` --> `computer-2`: OK
2. `computer-1` --> `computer-3`: Doesn't work
3. `computer-2` --> `computer-1`: OK
4. `computer-2` --> `computer-3`: OK
5. `computer-3` --> `computer-1`: Doesn't work
6. `computer-3` --> `computer-2`: OK

@Spiff suggested I find out what name-to-IP-address resolution scheme is in use on each PC -- how can I find this out?

Comment: are these all windows 10 systems? no win7, or linux, or IOT? I'd confirm they are all configured to use SMB3/NTLMv3. seems like computer 3 is the problem child, so how is it different?

Comment: One of your troubleshooting methods needs to be this.  When you can't see one machine from another, try the IP ADDRESS and not the machine name and see if that works.  Name resolution is not the same as a port being blocked or service not avail.  If it turns out to be a name resolution problem, there are many workarounds which will differ completely from other problems.  They can all be solved but you need to figure out what the actual problem is first.

Comment: It would be helpful to know which name-to-IP-address resolution schemes you're using on each PC. NetBIOS Name Service? WINS? DNS? /etc/hosts? LLMNR? mDNS? It would also be helpful to know if PC1 and PC3 have any connectivity to each other at all. For example, can they ping each other by name? Can they ping each other by IP address?

Comment: @Spiff - how can I find out what name-to-IP-address resolution scheme is in use on each PC?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - updated the post: exactly the same combination of ability/inability for the PCS to connect to each other using IP address instead of PC name.

Comment: @FrankThomas - Yes: all are Windows 10 systems. I just let Windows update itself whenever the sleep/shutdown icon is replaced with "update & sleep" or "update & shutdown" -- so I assume all PCs are reasonably up-to-date with wherever Microsoft deems they ought to be. It is also interesting that all PCs were able to connect to each other in the past, and I haven't tinkered with any underlying networking or any of the PC's respective names or workgroups.

Comment: if you go into secpol.msc on computer-3, are most of the settings the same as the other systems? things like SCHANNEL settings, SMB signing, etc? do any of the computers have SMBv1 support installed?